# Priority queues O(1) insert, delete-min and decrease-key?

Tags: heap, complexity-theory, priority-queue

I saw this "Hopeless challenge" about priority queues in an algorithms book :

" O(1) insert, delete-min and decrease-key. Why is it impossible?"

Is it because the only way is to implement it with some sort of heap and heaps always take logn time to to delete-min (even if amortized)?

Comment: What is your practical programming problem? This sounds like a theoretical problem, not a practical one.

Comment: Yes it's theoretical.

Comment: StackOverflow is for practical programming problems. Purely theoretical ones are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the well-known fact that sorting n integers requires time n * log(n) and I assume that delete-min actually finds the minimum (and could, for instance return it).

Toward a contradiction, suppose we have a data structure such as the one you described. Then, in order to sort n integers, we first insert all of them into the data structure, thus taking time O(n). We then repeatedly delete-min until the structure is empty. This gives us the sorted integers in time O(n), giving us a contradiction. Therefore, that data structure cannot exist.